# display only recent items in gnome dash

Tags: gnome, preferences, gnome-dash

It appears that with 22.04, the dash can only display ALL apps. It was previously possible to display RECENTLY USED. Is this option still available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option has disappeared. In revenge, the application overview now is fully customizable: you place your few most frequent apps on the Dash (and they do not anymore appear elsewhere in the Application overview then), your other most important apps on top of the first screen, and you group your utilities etc. like you want.

This gives an application overview which remains static, which is yours, so where you get to quickly find that application because you learn to know where it is.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium. I'm back on 20.04 for the present, but I will return to this shortly.

Comment: Got this now, @vanadium. Thanks.